# iOS/Safari: "Back" button on FileDownload screen sometimes missing

Tags: ios, download, safari, progressive-web-apps

Currently I'm facing a weird problem where I don't have any clue (because of this sorry for the very vague question). I've developed an Angular Web Application, that offers a file download. Now the weird part:

When testing on iOS (13.3, iPad, iPhone), basically everything is working. Then I did some variation of my test: I used the "Add to home screen" feature, where the web-app basically pretends to be a PWA, and iOS/Safari is opened without any browser UI.

In this mode, Safari handles file downloads a bit differently: When downloading a file, it shows a full-screen Overlay with the file name and some options, and some "Back/Done" button in the top bar (see screenshot below, where I download a test file "image.jpg").

The problem is that on some iOS devices on some test servers, exactly this button is missing in Safari, everything else is working.

Any idea what could trigger this behavior in iOS/Safari?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

iOS PWAs have been really buggy with small issues like this because of certain new iOS features such as the [Safari Download Manager](https://www.cultofmac.com/629362/safari-download-manager-ios-13/) in browser so Apple either hasn't realized or decided how they want to handle these bugs in PWAs.

I'd suggest to try out some different options to download your test files: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/95911